# fomatear fecha Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Buenas tardes necesito ayuda dandole formato a una fecha en angular8 he buscado y encontre que se puede utilizar (DatePipe) pero al momento de inyectarlo en el constructor me sale un error:

```
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CrearUsuarioComponent -> DatePipe]:
```

no se cual es el error

mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
constructor(pprivate datePipe: DatePipe){}


obtenerFecha(fecha){
    this.datePipe.transform(fecha,'dd/MM/yyyy');
    this.fechaform=this.datePipe.transform(fecha, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
    console.log(this.fechaform);
  }
```

Comment: ¿El formato es estético, o debes pasar la fecha a alguna parte? Si es lo primero, basta con usar el pipe `date` en tu template, y ese viene integrado en Angular, puedes ir y usarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los pipes están principalmente destinados a ser usados en el template, para formatear una fecha por ejemplo puedes usar este pipe de Angular.

```
{{ youtDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}
```

Si deseas usarlo en el componente debes agregarlo a tus providers en tu module

```
providers: [DatePipe,...]
```

Answer (score 0):

**RESPUESTA VÁLIDA PARA ANGULARJS o ANGULAR 1.X** puesta aquí por no aceptarse la pregunta [¿Formatear fecha en Angular?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361477/formatear-fecha-en-angular) al rechazarse por duplicada

Los filtros de tipo `Date` permiten imprimir las fechas en el formato deseado.

Si necesitas hacerlo dentro de una variable, en el código, puedes hacerlo con [$filter('date')](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {

  const date = new Date();
   $scope.fecha = date;
   console.log($filter('date')(date, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'));
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <p id="mifecha">{{fecha | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'}}</p>
</div>
```