# ¿Cómo formateo fecha y horas en AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs, date

Esto utilizando un input type="datetime-local" en AngularJS para mostrar un calendario y hora y necesito formatear esa fecha que obtengo.

Actualmente lo que me imprime es "2020-06-01T12:10".

Tengo una función que solo me formatea la fecha en modo YYYY-mm-dd, faltaría la hora:

```
getDate() {
    const date = new Date();
    this.today = date.getFullYear() + '-'
             + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-'
             + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
             console.log(this.today);
  }
```

¿Cómo podría implementarlo para que me quede como lo que imprimo, es decir de esta manera: "2020-06-01T12:10"?

Comment: Revisa si te vale esta solución. Parece que la preguna ya se ha respondido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/334426/16285

Comment: Realmente no, mirare que otra opción hay, de todas maneras muchas gracias

Comment: No veo nada de angular en tu código. Te paso una solución que funciona.

Comment: Vos marcaste (aunque sea sin querer) que la pregunta marcada como duplicada, te servia? si no te sirve, por favor aclaralo y borramos la duplicidad entre las mismas.

Comment: Es demasiado importante revises [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los filtros de tipo `Date` permiten imprimir las fechas en el formato deseado.

Si necesitas hacerlo dentro de una variable, en el código, puedes hacerlo con [$filter('date')](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {

  const date = new Date();
   $scope.fecha = date;
   console.log($filter('date')(date, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'));
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <p id="mifecha">{{fecha | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'}}</p>
</div>
```